# Token Speech to text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

The script does not accept the Google token for speech to text. I create a Google token and enable speech to text. But the server throws a 403 error , as if I entered the wrong token. But it is true, the same length as the friend. The friend token works. What is the problem? Sorry for mistakes, I use a translator. I will be grateful for any response![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Screen photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWH4W.jpg

Comment: Is the image in your comments the same one as they question?

Comment: Yes. In the photo, the answer in the console when entering by token